# Do the bullets that bounce off riot shields and kill people count as a kill for the person shooting or the person with the riot shield?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

The intel sometimes says that "Bullets can ricochet off riot shields and kill!" which I have never seen happen. Anyway, I was wondering that if this were to occur, who would get the kill for it, the person shooting, or the person with the riot shield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The person shooting at the Riot Shield gets the kill from the ricochet, shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_fGxTrE40g):